# Inpainting looks blurry

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, watermark, inpainting

I want to remove a watermark from a image and result looks blurry on the watermarks. I need help to fix this.

Original Image
[image: Original Image]

Mask
[image: Mask]

Result
[image: Result]

I have used the inpaint function from opencv. My code looks like this.

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np
import time 

start = time.time()

IMAGE = "images/img.jpg"
MASK = "images/mask.png"

image = cv2.imread(IMAGE)
mask = cv2.imread(MASK, 0)

img = cv2.inpaint(image, mask, 0, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", img)

print(time.time()-start)
```

Comment: I don't see blurry?  I see gaps created.  Perhaps you need to apply some morphology to your mask to broaden the mask and perhaps make it binary.

Comment: i am wondering where the blury parts are too ?   please show the blur.

Comment: the basic `INPAINT_NS` is always gonna be blurry. your expectations don't match the algorithm. -- your mistake is expecting to *entirely* replace those areas. you have a watermark. the background shines through. you should reconsider your approach to removing the watermark.

Comment: Sorry for my english. Yes i mean this gaps, how can i remove it that it looks more clean?

Answer (score 2):

There are some artifacts that the in-painting algorithm produces; it's difficult to completely get rid of them. This is my take trying to minimize the artifacts. It basically involves converting the `BGR` image to `LAB`, splitting the `L` channel, in-painting only this channel, merging the components and then converting back to `BGR`:

```
import cv2

# Set image path
directoryPath = "D://opencvImages//"

# Load image:
inputImage = cv2.imread(directoryPath + "GzRoc.jpg")
showImage("Input Image", inputImage)

# To LAB:
labImage = cv2.cvtColor(inputImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
# Split LAB Image:
L, A, B = cv2.split(labImage)

# Load mask:
maskImage = cv2.imread(directoryPath + "H5DpA.png")
showImage("Input Mask", maskImage)

# Mask to grayscale:
maskImage = cv2.cvtColor(maskImage, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

It appears that your mask is a little bit bigger than your input image. Let’s `resize` it because the in-painting algorithm needs exactly the same sizes for both images:

```
# Resize mask:
imageHeight, imageWidth = inputImage.shape[:2]
newSize = (imageWidth, imageHeight)
maskImage = cv2.resize(maskImage, newSize, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)

# Threshold mask:
_, binaryMask = cv2.threshold(maskImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

Let’s apply a little bit of morphology. Looks like a basic `dilation` helps mitigating the artifacts:

```
# Prepare in-paint mask:
kernelSize = (3, 3)
morphoKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, kernelSize)
inpaintMask = cv2.morphologyEx(binaryMask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, morphoKernel, iterations=1)
```

Now, let’s in-paint the `L` channel, merge it with the rest of the original components and convert back to `BGR`:

```
# In-paint the L channel:
inpaintedL = cv2.inpaint(L, inpaintMask, 0, cv2.INPAINT_NS)

# Merge LAB:
labImage = cv2.merge([inpaintedL, A, B])

# LAB to BGR:
outImage = cv2.cvtColor(labImage, cv2.COLOR_LAB2BGR)

cv2.imshow("OutImage", outImage)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:

[image]

**Observation:** Save your images using a lossless format such as `png`, your original image is `jpeg` and you can see some compression artifacts already before performing any processing.

Comment: That perfect, mate.. Usually, I used mouseevent.  But didn't realise this  COLOR_BGR2LAB). Upvote for you.

Comment: Looks not bad, thank you for your help! But i mean to remove the gaps. If you look close to the image there are gaps. You can see the watermark. I know thats not a easy task. I dont know i think a trained model will solve it. What you think?

Comment: I can see it on watermark.